# Is there a way to have one test function appearing as multiple unit tests in JUnit?

Tags: java, xml, junit

I have a kx q project with unit tests. This test suite produces a table with the test results and I need to integrate this with Atlassian Bamboo to see what tests failed and why. The easier way would be to dump this test result table into a csv that would be then converted to a JUnit XML output that Atlassian Bamboo plugins already understand.

To this end I think the best would be to have a Java project with a single test suite or single function that reads each line (each line in that CSV is a separate test case) of this CSV and asserts against whether the corresponding line passed or failed the test. The important thing is that each assertion is taken as a separate test within the test suite so the JUnit XML output correspond one to one to the csv file dump.

Can this be done using JUnit and how?

Comment: Is this question really about converting some existing non-JUnit test output from some table format to JUnit XML format? If so, you shouldn't fake JUnit tests, but rather write code to convert from one format to another.

Comment: The reason is maintainability. I would need to update such tool every time the JUnit XML output schema changes.

Comment: The format hasn't changed in many years, and lots of tools are relying on it, so it's very unlikely going to change in the future. Even if it changes, you'll be much better off with a direct translation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can this be done using JUnit

I wouldn't expect so, mostly because the behavior being described isn't strictly a *unit test* per se.  Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the question (correct me if that's the case), but it sounds like what you want to do is:

> Repeat a single test for every line of an input file, and indicate the results individually.

That's a test of sorts, validating a file as input into the system.  But it's not testing the *behavior of the code* which puts it a bit outside the scope of unit tests.

Unless there's a tool which does something similar to this, I'd be inclined to simply build one.  All it really needs to do is receive the file as input, invoke a "test" over each line (which *could* be a unit test method, but doesn't necessarily need to be), and output results to a file of its own.  As an implementation detail that output happens to be XML in the same format that JUnit outputs its results, so that the same tools can read the results.

As unit tests alone I imagine it would necessitate treating *each line* of the input as a separate *statically defined* test (where each line of input is the "arrange" step).  Which certainly wouldn't be ideal.  I imagine writing a one-off tool to be invoked on its own would be a shorter path to the goal than trying to force JUnit into a pattern it wasn't intended for.

Unless as a concern of automated build/deploy steps it's necessary for this validation to be unit tests, a one-off tool seems more straightforward.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tend to agree with this but I would not like to have to change this new tool every time a new JUnit XML output schema is released. This is the main reason why I'd prefer not to build a separate (though more straightforward solution) tool. It would be more future-proven to simply map each line in the CSV to a fake unit test.

Comment: @GiovanniAzua: Interesting, does the JUnit output format change that frequently?  It doesn't really affect my answer or your intent, I'm just curious since I haven't actually used it before and haven't had to follow that particular standard.  It seems particularly strange to me that this would be an issue.